# Mobo dead, how to access striped volume externally from laptop?

Tags: data-recovery, raid-0, disk-management, dynamic-disk

I have a dead PC with 2 data drives that are windows striped (not hardware raid-0). If I buy a usb raid enclosure, do you think windows will recognize them as a dynamic disc? If not, is there a way to access it externally without a desktop? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it was done in Windows (e.g. through Disk Management), then yes, another Windows OS will recognize it. Don't expect to be able to boot from them on your laptop though.

Doing it over USB may introduce some wrinkles, but should work fine in theory if Windows can see the individual drives.